# Firebase will create a new user, but won't return the user object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase V9 with React. When I fill out the fields below, Firebase will create a new user for me, but it won't return the user object. When I try to `console.log(user)`, nothing appears. Where am I going wrong here?

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase-config';

function Signup() {
  const [registerEmail, setRegisterEmail] = useState('');
  const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState('');

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser);
  });

  const register = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        registerEmail,
        registerPassword
      );
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-full flex flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <a href="/">
          <img
            className="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
            src="./img/logo-orange.png"
            alt="HBD Logo"
          />
        </a>
        <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
          Sign up for your free account
        </h2>
        <p className="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600">
          Already have an account?{' '}
          <a
            href="/signin"
            className="font-medium text-orange-600 hover:text-orange-500"
          >
            Sign in.
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <div className="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
          <form className="space-y-6">
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setRegisterEmail(event.target.value);
                  }}
                  autoComplete="email"
                  type="email"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-orange-500 focus:border-orange-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Password
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1 space-y-6">
                <input
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setRegisterPassword(event.target.value);
                  }}
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  type="password"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-orange-500 focus:border-orange-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={register}
                className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
              >
                Sign up
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: If you try to log something else after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, does that log? Also try updating to latest V9.X.X version if you are using any older version

Comment: It's so bizarre. If I replace the content after "return (" with a basic form with no Tailwind CSS content, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why yet...but the culprit seemed to be the <form> tag in the HTML.